# Is there a way to draw arrows from/to table rows in PlantUML?

Tags: uml, erd, plantuml

If you had an ER-Diagram in PlantUML, stylized this way using tables, is there a way to connect the table rows with arrows?

```
@startuml
entity User {
  <#transparent,#transparent>| <color:gold><&key> | <b>id |<r> bigint |
  | | name |<r> varchar |
}

entity Email {
  <#transparent,#transparent>| <color:gold><&key> | <b>id |<r> bigint |
  | <color:purple><&link-intact> | <i>user_id |<r> bigint |
  | | address |<r> varchar |
}

User::id -> Email::user_id
@enduml
```

[image: PlantUML Preview]

I know you can get exactly what I want using fields, but the way it looks is a bit boring and simple.

Also, there is a bit of micromanagement by putting the tabs characters.

```
@startuml
entity User {
  #id \t\t bigint
  name \t varchar
}

entity Email {
  #id    \t\t bigint
  +user_id \t bigint
  address  \t varchar
}

User::id -> Email::user_id
@enduml
```

[image: PlantUML Preview]

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround that will not involve the tab micromanagement in the member/fields approach.

You can design a procedure, to take care of the tabs characters for you. The only thing left is to replace the member visibility icons (something I do not know how to do).

This approach requires the table data to be store as a JSON (one per each table).

For example:

> **table.iuml**
>
> ```
> @startuml
> !global $tab_size = 4 ' The tab size in plantuml is 4 chars wide
>
> ' Returns the size in tabs, rounded down, that the $data has
> !function $tab_size($data)
> !return %strlen($data)/$tab_size
> !endfunction
>
> ' Get the maximum number of tabs from the $data array
> !function $get_max_tabs($data)
> !local $tabs = 0
> !foreach $field in $data
> !local $field_tabs = $tab_size($field.name)
> !if ($tabs < $field_tabs)
> !local $tabs = $field_tabs
> !endif
> !endfor
> !return $tabs
> !endfunction
>
> ' Get the field name followed by the "perfect" number of tabs
> !function $get_name($name, $max_tabs)
> !local $tabs = "\t"
> !local $length = $tab_size($name)
> !while $max_tabs > $length
> !local $tabs = $tabs + "\t"
> !local $length = $length + 1
> !endwhile
> !return $name + $tabs
> !endfunction
>
> ' Create a entity member for the table field
> !procedure field($data, $max_tabs)
> !local $field = $get_name($data.name, $max_tabs) + $data.type
> !if %json_key_exists($data, "index")
> !if $data.index == "primary"
> # $field
> !elseif $data.index == "unique"
> ~ $field
> !elseif $data.index == "simple"
> + $field
> !endif
> !else
> $field
> !endif
> !endprocedure
>
> ' Process the JSON data to create a plantuml entity 
> !procedure table($data)
> !local $tabs = $get_max_tabs($data.fields)
> entity $data.name {
>     !foreach $field in $data.fields
>     field($field, $tabs)
>     !endfor
> }
> !endprocedure
> @enduml
> ```

> **database.puml**
>
> ```
> @startuml
> !include table.iuml
>
> !$user = %load_json("user.json")
> table($user) 
>
> !$email = %load_json("email.json")
> table($email)
>
> user::id -> email::user_id
> @enduml
> ```

> **user.json**
>
> ```json
> {
>     "name": "user",
>     "fields": [
>         {
>             "name": "id",
>             "type": "bigint",
>             "index": "primary"
>         },
>         {
>             "name": "name",
>             "type": "varchar"
>         }
>     ]
> }
> ```

> **email.json**
>
> ```json
> {
>     "name": "email",
>     "fields": [
>         {
>             "name": "id",
>             "type": "bigint",
>             "index": "primary"
>         },
>         {
>             "name": "user_id",
>             "type": "bigint"
>         },
>         {
>             "name": "address",
>             "type": "varchar"
>         }
>     ]
> }
> ```

Obtaining the following diagram

[image: Diagram obtained]